# How write firestore query filter for array of objects?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, compound-query

I am writing a query in react native to get data from **firestore** by filtration of friends by friend name ... Like get all useers where friendName is XYZ

```
[
{User: 'Johan', friends:[{friendName: 'ABC', age:20}, {friendName: 'DEF', age:30},{friendName: 'XYZ', age:25}]}, 

{User: 'Johnson', friends:[{friendName: 'ABC', age:20}, {friendName: 'XYZ', age:25}]},

{User: 'Symonds', friends:[{friendName: 'DEF', age:30},{friendName: 'XYZ', age:25}]}
]
```

I am trying with code like this by is not working. As I need to mention to filter with **friendName** but not able to find how to write this in query.

```
usersRef
    .doc(userId)
    .collection("Users")
    .where('friends', 'array-contains','ABC')
    .get();
```

Comment: Have you checked this? [How to use array-contains operator with an array of objects in Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68188508)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

as long as I Know you can't query fields inside objects. My approach would be querying user's id, and then iterate resulting array.

```
//First make a query 
let resultsArray=[]
usersRef.doc(userId).collection("Users").get().then((docs)=>{
 this.resultsArray.push(docs)
})

//after query is done, iterate results
this.resultsArray.foreach((item)=>{
  item.data().friends.foreach((friend)=>{
    if(friend.friendName === 'ABC'){
      //yes, your friend name is ABC, do whatever you need.
    }
 )
})
```

Comment: What if we have 3.5 billion Users? Can you calculate the costs of firebase traffic?

Comment: if you have 3.5 billion users, you'll probably have the money to pay for the firebase traffic :)

Comment: that's why you will always have 141 points ;)